# how do I access this json data in python?

Tags: python, json

hi I'm pretty new at coding and I was trying to create a program in python that reads and save in another file the data inside a json file (not everything, just what I want). I googled how to parse data but there's something I don't understand.

that's a part of the json file:

`

```
{
 "profileRevision": 548789,
 "profileId": "campaign",
 "profileChangesBaseRevision": 548789,
 "profileChanges": [
  {
   "changeType": "fullProfileUpdate",
   "profile": {
    "_id": "2da4f079f8984cc48e84fc99dace495d",
    "created": "2018-03-29T11:02:15.190Z",
    "updated": "2022-10-31T17:34:43.284Z",
    "rvn": 548789,
    "wipeNumber": 9,
    "accountId": "63881e614ef543b2932c70fed1196f34",
    "profileId": "campaign",
    "version": "refund_teddy_perks_september_2022",
    "items": {
     "8ec8f13f-6bf6-4933-a7db-43767a055e66": {
      "templateId": "Quest:heroquest_loadout_constructor_2",
      "attributes": {
       "quest_state": "Claimed",
       "creation_time": "min",
       "last_state_change_time": "2019-05-18T16:09:12.750Z",
       "completion_complete_pve03_diff26_loadout_constructor": 300,
       "level": -1,
       "item_seen": true,
       "sent_new_notification": true,
       "quest_rarity": "uncommon",
       "xp_reward_scalar": 1
      },
      "quantity": 1
     },
     "6940c71b-c74b-4581-9f1e-c0a87e246884": {
      "templateId": "Worker:workerbasic_sr_t01",
      "attributes": {
       "gender": "2",
       "personality": "Homebase.Worker.Personality.IsDreamer",
       "level": 1,
       "item_seen": true,
       "squad_slot_idx": -1,
       "portrait": "WorkerPortrait:IconDef-WorkerPortrait-Dreamer-F02",
       "building_slot_used": -1,
       "set_bonus": "Homebase.Worker.SetBonus.IsMeleeDamageLow"
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

`

I can access profileChanges. I wrote this to create another json file with only the profileChanges things:

`

```
myjsonfile= open("file.json",'r') 
        jsondata=myjsonfile.read() 
        obj=json.loads(jsondata)  
        ciso=obj['profileChanges']
        for i in ciso:
            print(i)
        with open("file2", "w") as outfile:
            json.dump( ciso, outfile, indent=1)
```

the issue I have is that I can't access "profile" (inside profileChanges) in the same way by parsing the new file and I have no idea on how to do it

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Access to JSON or dict element is realized by list indexes, please look at below example:

```
a = [
  {
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Reba May"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Doris Gallagher! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
]

b = a['friends']['id] # b = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a couple of closing braces to make your snippet valid json:

```py
s = '''{
 "profileRevision": 548789,
 "profileId": "campaign",
 "profileChangesBaseRevision": 548789,
 "profileChanges": [
  {
   "changeType": "fullProfileUpdate",
   "profile": {
    "_id": "2da4f079f8984cc48e84fc99dace495d",
    "created": "2018-03-29T11:02:15.190Z",
    "updated": "2022-10-31T17:34:43.284Z",
    "rvn": 548789,
    "wipeNumber": 9,
    "accountId": "63881e614ef543b2932c70fed1196f34",
    "profileId": "campaign",
    "version": "refund_teddy_perks_september_2022",
    "items": {
     "8ec8f13f-6bf6-4933-a7db-43767a055e66": {
      "templateId": "Quest:heroquest_loadout_constructor_2",
      "attributes": {
       "quest_state": "Claimed",
       "creation_time": "min",
       "last_state_change_time": "2019-05-18T16:09:12.750Z",
       "completion_complete_pve03_diff26_loadout_constructor": 300,
       "level": -1,
       "item_seen": true,
       "sent_new_notification": true,
       "quest_rarity": "uncommon",
       "xp_reward_scalar": 1
      },
      "quantity": 1
     },
     "6940c71b-c74b-4581-9f1e-c0a87e246884": {
      "templateId": "Worker:workerbasic_sr_t01",
      "attributes": {
       "gender": "2",
       "personality": "Homebase.Worker.Personality.IsDreamer",
       "level": 1,
       "item_seen": true,
       "squad_slot_idx": -1,
       "portrait": "WorkerPortrait:IconDef-WorkerPortrait-Dreamer-F02",
       "building_slot_used": -1,
       "set_bonus": "Homebase.Worker.SetBonus.IsMeleeDamageLow"
     }
    }
   }
   }
   }
  ]
 }
'''
d = json.loads(s)
print(d['profileChanges'][0]['profile']['version'])
```

This prints `refund_teddy_perks_september_2022`

Explanation:

- `d` is a `dict`
- `d['profileChanges']` is a list of dicts
- `d['profileChanges'][0]` is the first `dict` in the list
- `d['profileChanges'][0]['profile']` is a `dict`
- `d['profileChanges'][0]['profile']['version']` is the value of `version` key in the `profile` dict in the first entry of the `profileChanges` list.